# How can I override operator== to compare two objects?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace

class Book{
    string title;
    int price, pages;
public:
    Book(string title = "", int price = 0, int pages = 0){
        this->title = title;
        this->price = price;
        this->pages = pages;
    }
    bool operator==(Book);
};
bool Book::operator==(Book op1){
    if(*(this) == op1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main()
    Book a("Good C++", 30000, 500), b("Bad C++", 30000, 500);
    if (a == b)
        cout << "Same books" << endl;
}
```

When run the code. I get the following error

> zsh: segmentation fault  ./main

How can I compare two objects?

```
this == op1
```

I tried this, but an error occurred because the data format is different

Comment: Well, the program as currently written has multiple errors that would result in it not compiling.  But also, your `operator==` is infinitely recursive.  You need to compare all the member variables, with the appropriate logic.

Comment: `*(this) == op1` in the `operator==()` function expands to `(*this).operator==(op1)` which is equivalent to `this->operator(op1)`.    So the operator calls itself, resulting in infinite recursion - hence the untime error.   You need to write code that compares the individual members (e.g. `return title == op1.title && price == op1.price && pages == op1.pages` (or, more verbosely, the equivalent `return this->title == op1.title && this->price == op1.price && this->pages == op1.pages`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually perform the comparison within the operator. The way you had it, the == operator calls itself, which would end up causing a crash.

```cpp
class Book{
    string title;
    int price, pages;
public:
    Book(string title = "", int price = 0, int pages = 0){
        this->title = title;
        this->price = price;
        this->pages = pages;
    }
    bool operator==(const Book&) const;
};
bool Book::operator==(const Book& op1) const{
    return title == op1.title && 
           price == op1.price && 
           pages == op1.pages;
}
```

Comment: It would be worth also pointing out the two modifications you made to const-correctness of the `operator==` function itself, and illustrating why that's important.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool Book::operator==(Book &op1){
    if(*(this) == op1) // this lines calls the operator== function again.
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The mentioned code is the wrong way of comparing objects.
The above code keeps on calling the operator == again and again which result in segmentation fault

You have to compare each attributes(or any number of attribute as per requirement).
The above code can be rewritten as:

```
bool Book::operator==(const Book& op1) const{
    return (title == op1.title && price == op1.price && pages == op1.pages);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C++20 you can put:

```
bool operator== (const Book&) const = default;
```

which does the same comparison you were trying to code.

You can write `auto operator<=>` instead of `bool operator==` to get all the relational comparison operators as well.

Prior to C++20 you can still keep your code tidy using `tie` to combine all the members into one expression:

```
bool Book::operator==(const Book& op1) const
{
    return std::tie(title, price, pages) == std::tie(op1.title, op1.price, op1.pages);
}
```